# FATAL EXCEPTION Android wear heart rate App

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-sensors, heartbeat

I am trying to make a heart rate monitor app on Android wear, and when I try to run app on my device (LG G watch R) I have

> "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

and on Android studio I see this error:

[image: My error]

```
package com.example.ryuu.appka;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class activity_wear extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private TextView mTextView;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TextView mTextViewStepCount;
private TextView mTextViewStepDetect;
private TextView mTextViewHeart;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_wear);

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mTextViewStepCount = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.step_count);
            mTextViewStepDetect = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.step_detect);
            mTextViewHeart = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.heart);
            getStepCount();
        }
    });
}

private void getStepCount() {
    SensorManager mSensorManager = ((SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    Sensor mStepCountSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    Sensor mStepDetectSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCountSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

private String currentTimeStr() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
        String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
        mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        String msg = "Count: " + (int)event.values[0];
        mTextViewStepCount.setText(msg);
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        String msg = "Detected at " + currentTimeStr();
        mTextViewStepDetect.setText(msg);
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
    else
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
}
```

}

Whole source code is on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fE0u57NGnGUEFxZWUyUm5GWG8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `mTextViewHeart` is `null`. Apparently at the time that the `onSensorChanged()` method is called, the `mTextViewHeart` is not yet initialized.

You can prevent that by checking if it is not `null` before trying to invoke a method on it.

Also read [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to help you understand your problem better.

Comment: Shame of me, but be honest, i have no idea why I have null here ;/